# LINQ Take() returns the same results over and over

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to page over some records but the `Take()` extension from `LINQ` isn't returning the result which I expected.

```
public IQueryable<Person> GetPersonBetweenDates(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
  return dbcontext.Persons.Where(x => x.RegisterDate >= start && x.RegisterDate <= end).Take(20);
}
```

When I run this method again, I get the same result. How exactly does `Take()` work?

Comment: Add two parameters: `personNumber` and `personCount`. Then you could use the in `Skip` and `Take`.

Comment: You aren't using OrderBy so the order is undefined anyway.

Comment: It doesn't delete the elements you "Take", if that is your confusion. Otherwise its plainly obvious it _takes_ 20 items from the left query/enumerable... which in this case never changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Take` method returns the first N records (N being the parameter) or all of the records if the total is less than N.  To implement paging use it in conjunction with `Skip`, specifying how many records to skip before taking the next page of results.  You may also want to supply some total ordering to ensure that the query returns results in the same order each time.

Note: I've assumed zero-based paging.

```
private const int _pageSize = 20;

public IQueryable<Person> GetPersonBetweenDates(DateTime start, DateTime end, int? page)
{
     return dbcontext.Persons
                     .Where(x => x.RegisterDate >= start && x.RegisterDate <= end)
                     .OrderBy(x => x.LastName)
                     .ThenBy(x => x.FirstName)
                     .ThenBy(x => x.Id) // using unique id to force consistent total order
                     .Skip((page ?? 0) * _pageSize)
                     .Take(_pageSize);
}
```

Comment: Assuming of course `Person` has a `LastName`, `FirstName`, and unique `Id`.

Comment: Ok now I get it, the `Take()` has to work with the `Skip()` for it to pass the next set of records. I did read that I have to order the result, but why so many `OrderBy`'s?

Comment: @Yustme You can't guarantee that if you don't specify the order your output will be the same every time, so say 25 people have the last name `Anderson`, if you did not also sort by first name (then Id to make sure people who share the same first and last name are sorted correctly) you could have people who showed up in the first set of 20 also show up in the next set of 20 because it would be totally up to the data source how it wants to sort those 25 Andersons, all you told it to do is make sure "Anderson" comes before "Chamberlain".

Comment: @Yustme I included the example to show the concept of total order (as Scott Chamberlin describes), http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order. Obviously you could simply order by `Id` which provides a total order by itself, but usually with people you want an ordering by name - thus the example of using the `Id` property to force the total ordering.

Answer (score 5):

`.Take` returns the specified number of results on a query, and if it is the same query it will often return the same results. To resolve this, you might use a combination of `.Skip` and `.Take`, changing the number you are `Skip`ping and `Take`ing each time.

```
private int counter = 0;
public IQueryable<Person> GetPersonBetweenDates(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var results = dbcontext.Persons.Where(x => x.RegisterDate >= start && x.RegisterDate <= end).Skip(counter).Take(20);
    counter += 20;
    return results;
}
```

Keep in mind that you will be able to call this continuously, even after there are no more records.

Alternatively, you could cache the query (if you aren't reinstantiating the class on each use):

```
private IQueryable<Person> qry = dbcontext.Persons.Where(x => x.RegisterDate >= start && x.RegisterDate <= end);
public IQueryable<Person> GetPersonBetweenDates(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    qry = qry.Skip(20);
    return qry.Take(20);
}
```

Nevertheless, both of these snippets may have other issues -- see tvanfosson's comments and answer.

Comment: While what you say is true, your reasoning is not. The fact that each call to `Where` creates a new query is irrelevant. After `var query = dbcontext.Where(...); var take1 = query.Take(20); var take2 = query.Take(20);`, `take1` and `take2` should give the same results.

Comment: I was willing to upvote this until you added your examples. I would never implement either way.  In neither case, can you page "backwards" and that's not the only problem.

Comment: @tvanfosson The OP's example also doesn't allow paging backwards.

Comment: @ZevSpitz fair enough, but (a) your examples aren't very flexible, (b) in the second case if it's generating SQL the query is going to get worse with each use, (c) if the class is instantiated for each request (say in a web context), they don't actually improve the situation.

Comment: @tvanfosson The primary focus of my answer was not to provide a paging solution, but to illustrate with code how it is that `Take` doesn't work like the OP thought it should.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I've got nothing personal against you. I just think your code could be improved. I think when you provide an example, it should be technically sound. I can't upvote an answer with an example that isn't - because people WILL copy/paste code. I've found that when I get feedback it's better for everyone if I don't get defensive, but try to learn from it.